# CMD escape spaces and exclude names containing specific string

Tags: string, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, escaping

The code is like this but it doesn't work as expected right now:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f %%i in ('dir *.mov /b') do call :test %%i
goto continue
  :test
  if "%1"=="*compressed.mov" goto :eof
  echo "%~f1"
  goto :eof
:continue
pause
```

I would like to solve two problems here:

1. How to escape spaces in file names? ie. I would like to include "video 1.mov" file for the test and not echo just the "Drive:\path\video" but instead "Drive:\path\video 1.mov"
2. How to not echo any file containing string "compressed" at the end of it's name?

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir *.mov /b^|findstr /i /e /v /L /c:"compressed.mov"') do call :test %%i`

Comment: @Magoo this does solve the second problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would suit:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In ("*.mov") Do If /I "%%~xG" == ".mov" (Set "_=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If /I Not "!_:~-10!" == "compressed" (EndLocal & Echo "%%~fG"
    ) Else EndLocal
)
Pause
```

Alternatively use `findstr.exe`:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "*.mov" /A:-D /B 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIE ".mov" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /VLIE "compressed.mov"') Do @Echo "%__CD__%%%G"
@Pause
```